# Odoo POS create invoice after POS session is closed

Tags: python, odoo-8, invoice, point-of-sale, accounting

Anybody knows why it's not possible to generate an invoice after that the POS session is closed an the POS orders are booked?
And how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need be fixed, because it is not a bug, when you close the session you post the entries and reconcile payments, and I see that for security reasons too, you don't want some user invoiced a yesterday pos order, he could use the invoice for money laundering(I exaggerated the event).